# I can't see the purchased files

Tags: files, ubuntu-one, downloads

Yesterday I purchased an album with Ubuntu One, but I can't see the files. I logged in but I can't see them in the "purchased" folder, also the player says "queued", but it never changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have an issue getting purchased music please contact [Ubuntu One Support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/).